# Merging LiveData with different Object Contained

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

So I am writing an app using Room and LiveData.  It is a finance app.  I have two entities I am trying to merge, **Payee** and **Transaction**.  **Transaction** has a ForeignKey linking it to **Payee**.  I am using LiveData from Room all the way through (Daos, Repository, ViewModels) to my UI (Fragments).

I would like to combine these two data sets at some level before I get to the Fragment level but am not sure how to do it.  I know I can make a POJO with the Query straight from the database but I kind of want to have a **Transaction** Object with **Payee** in it rather than just all the fields from both.

Is there a way to do this?  Perhaps using one of the transformations (map or switchMap)?  Or maybe using MediatorLiveData?  Can they observe more than one data type (eg. LiveData and LiveData)?

Payee.java

```
@Entity
public class Payee {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo (name = "id")
    private int id;

    . . . 
}
```

Transaction.java

```
@Entity (foreignKeys =
        @ForeignKey(entity = Payee.class, 
                             parentColumns = "id", 
                             childColumns = "payee_id", 
                             onDelete = RESTRICT))
public class Transaction {

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo (name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo (name = "payee_id")
    private int payeeId;
    @Ignore
    private Payee payee;

    . . .
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want 2 LiveData sets (one for the Payee's and one for the Transactions) and create a 3rd LiveData with a particular relationship between the 2 others?

Comment: I am looking for some way to take as an input two LiveData of different types and provide a LiveData of one type that has the other as a child of the first.

Comment: Sounds like a MediatorLiveData case to me ... can you elaborate a bit more on how child and "parent" are linked? Or: which to LiveData sets would you like to monitor? LiveData<List<Payee>> and LiveData<List<Transaction>>? With MediatorLiveData you'd have to specify what happens if one of the 2 sets change ...

Answer (score 5):

The Transaction Object with Payee in it, will be produced by the @Embedded annotation, independently of being additional columns in your DAO query.

There are other scenarios related to your question:

- Entities that need completely independent queries. A MediatorLiveData with more than one Source will be required.
- Entities with one-to-many relation that cannot be fulfilled with the default SELECT * FROM query, generated by the @Relation annotation. A Transformations.switchMap can be used as explained below (I found your question while searching for this).

Using global executor pools, as demonstrated in Google GithubBrowserSample sample with the [AppExecutor](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/AppExecutors.java) class, the nested query in the repository class will end up like this:

```
public LiveData<QuotationCustomer> loadQuotationDetails(int quotationId) {
    LiveData<QuotationCustomer> quotationLiveData =
            quotationDao.getQuotationCustomer(quotationId);
    LiveData<QuotationCustomer> result =
            Transformations.switchMap(quotationLiveData, quotation -> {
        MutableLiveData<QuotationCustomer> mutableResult = new MutableLiveData<>();
        appExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
            quotation.quotationDetList = 
                    quotationDetDao.getQuotationDetsByQuotationIdSync(quotationId);
            mutableResult.postValue(quotation);
        });
        return mutableResult;
    });
    return result;
}
```

In the previous code sample, the getQuotationDetsByQuotationIdSync DAO method is returning a plain List (not a LiveData>) and the QuotationCustomer POJO extends an @Entity annotated class and has the quotationDetList property defined as follows:

```
@Ignore
public List<QuotationDetProductUnit> quotationDetList;
```

In your case, replace QuotationCustomer by Payee and QuotationDetProductUnit by Transaction.

Comment: Can we get question details with LiveData. Merge it somehow? I'm talking about this method: getQuotationDetsByQuotationIdSync(id), but returning LiveData<List<Details>>

Comment: @P.Savrov you can apply [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) instead of `Transformations.switchMap`, adding a first LiveData source and the code in the `Observer.onChange` could remove this first LiveData source and add a second LiveData source